# JOptionPane: Dialog Message box not opening in java

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I was trying to create a starting-level GUI in java. The GUI is simple I have three buttons, and when I click on any of them it should show a message box saying button X was clicked. But unfortunately, it was not opening any message box after I clicked the button. I don't know what went wrong, even after crosschecking multiple times. Can anyone please help, it would mean a lot to me.

Here is the code of the program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class jrames implements ActionListener {
    JButton jb1, jb2, jb3;
    JFrame frame;

    public jrames() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 300);
        Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(null);

        JButton jb1 = new JButton("Button A");
        jb1.setBounds(50, 75, 100, 40);
        cont.add(jb1);
        jb1.addActionListener(this);

        JButton jb2 = new JButton("Button B");
        jb2.setBounds(200, 75, 100, 40);
        cont.add(jb2);
        jb2.addActionListener(this);

        JButton jb3 = new JButton("Button C");
        jb3.setBounds(350, 75, 100, 40);
        cont.add(jb3);
        jb3.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jrames j1 = new jrames();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getSource() == jb1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Button A clicked");
            System.out.println("Button A clicked");
        }

        if (arg0.getSource() == jb2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Button B clicked");
        }

        if (arg0.getSource() == jb3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Button C clicked");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have create "instance" and "local" variables for all your buttons. The instance variables are null. Get rid of the local variable. Your "frame" variable is created correctly. The buttons must be created the same way.

Comment: ohh, now i get it what was wrong with the code, thank you for pointing it out.